# (Shell script) wpaclean <out.cap> <in.cap> for every .cap file in folder

Tags: bash, shell

I want to write a shell script in Linux, that will run the command wpaclean (usage: wpaclean <out.cap> <in.cap> ) and take every file in the current working directory as an argument.

For example, my shell script starts like this:

```
#! /bin/sh
cd /testfolder/
```

inside the folder there are numerous files: A.cap B.cap C.cap D.cap and so forth

Which commands do i need to put in the shell script, such that it automatically runs the command for every file in the directory and also automatically renames it?

Comment: `for file in *.cap`

Comment: `for $file in *.cap ; do SpecialCapCmd "$file" ; done` Now do research about the *nix utility `mv`. To read a help page about it, try `man mv` or `info mv`, else search the internet with `unix mv usage`. If you search here with `[linux] mv usage`, you'll find 90+ Q/A. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

for i in ./*.cap;do
    wpaclean "${i}" "${i%.*}-new.cap"
    mv "${i}" "${i%.*}"-old.cap
    echo "done with ${i}"
done
```

`${var%.*}` is a [parameter expansion](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/073) .